# C pointers, free memory

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

I have these structures:

```
typedef struct memory_slice {
    size_t startAdd; //Start of slice
    size_t dim; //Dim in bytes
    void *slice; //Chunk of memory
    struct memory_sclice *next; //Next element in list
} ms;

typedef struct heap_s {
    struct memory_slice *empty; //List of ptr to free memory
    struct memory_slice *used;
    heap_policy_t pol;
} heap_t;
```

I make two functions that work as constructor and destructor:

```
heap_t *heapCreate (size_t heapSize) {
    heap_t *p = malloc(sizeof(heap_t));

    if (heapSize != 0) {
        p->empty = malloc(sizeof(ms)); //Only one chunk
        p->empty->slice = malloc (sizeof(heapSize));
        p->empty->dim = heapSize;
    } else {
        p->empty = malloc(sizeof(ms));
        size_t ap = 1024;
        p->empty->slice = malloc (sizeof(ap));
        p->empty->dim = ap;
    }

    p->empty->startAdd = 0;
    p->empty->next = NULL;
    p->used = NULL;
    p->pol = first_fit;

    return p;
}

//Destructor of struct
void heapDestroy (heap_t *h) {
    //Free all slices
    struct memory_sclice *app;

    while (h->empty != NULL) {
        free(h->empty->slice);
        app = h->empty;
        h->empty = h->empty->next;
        free(app);
    }

    while (h->used != NULL) {
        free(h->used->slice);
        app = h->used;
        h->used = h->used->next;
        //free(app->slice);
        free(app);
    }

    free(h); //Delete main structure
}
```

This code works but I don't understand way I can't free memory like this "free(app->slice)" :

```
while (h->empty != NULL) {
        app = h->empty;
        free(app->slice);
        h->empty = h->empty->next;
        free(app);
    }
```

Can someone tell me where is the problem using "free(app->slice)" ??

Comment: What *precisely* is the problem? "I don't understand way I can't free memory like this `free(app->slice)`" - neither do I.

Comment: Compile error or runtime error?

Comment: At what point are you trying to call `free(app->slice)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's because you have a typo here:

```
struct memory_sclice *app;
```

It should be `memory_slice`.

Currently, `app` is not of type `memory_slice` and thus `slice` is not a member.

Basically, you have a pointer to a struct with no definition. (Unless for some very odd reason you have a struct in there called `memory_sclice` :V. I'd be surprised.)

Was this error really the only one that popped up?

Comment: This would wreak havoc with the compilation if compiled with much in the way of warnings.  I'm not sure it would have much effect at runtime, though.

Comment: Maybe the best solution is to call everything "ms" to avoid error so : "typedef struct ms {
    size_t startAdd; 
    size_t dim;
    void *slice; 
    struct memory_sclice *next; 
} ms;"

Answer (score 1):

The code supplied has a couple of references to `struct memory_cslice`; those need to be changed to `struct memory_slice`.  The code doesn't compile unless you add something like:

```
typedef enum { first_fit, best_fit, worst_fit } heap_policy_t;
```

Have you got and used [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) available to you?

There are two problematic calls to `malloc()` (not adjacent in the actual code):

```
p->empty->slice = malloc(sizeof(heapSize));
...
p->empty->slice = malloc(sizeof(ap));
```

In each case, the argument to `sizeof()` is of type `size_t`, so in fact the two blocks are allocating the same amount of space, and it is likely either 4 bytes or 8 bytes.  Very often it is correct to use `sizeof()` with `malloc()`; this is one of the cases where it is not correct.  You'd simplify your code if you wrote:

```
heap_t *heapCreate(size_t heapSize)
{
    heap_t *p = malloc(sizeof(heap_t));

    if (heapSize == 0)
        heapSize = 1024;
    p->empty = malloc(sizeof(ms));
    p->empty->slice = malloc(heapSize);
    p->empty->dim = heapSize;
    p->empty->startAdd = 0;
    p->empty->next = NULL;
    p->used = NULL;
    p->pol = first_fit;
    return p;
}
```

Of course, you should handle the cases where `malloc()` fails, so that should be improved to:

```
heap_t *heapCreate(size_t heapSize)
{
    heap_t *p = malloc(sizeof(heap_t));
    if (p != 0)
    {
        if (heapSize == 0)
            heapSize = 1024;
        if ((p->empty = malloc(sizeof(ms))) == 0)
        {
            free(p);
            return 0;
        }
        if ((p->empty->slice = malloc(heapSize)) == 0)
        {
            free(p->empty);
            free(p);
            return 0;
        }
        p->empty->dim = heapSize;
        p->empty->startAdd = 0;
        p->empty->next = NULL;
        p->used = NULL;
        p->pol = first_fit;
    }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for corrections, your code is cleaner that mine! I forgot to post that enum : "typedef enum {
first_fit,
best_fit,
worst_fit
} heap_policy_t;"

Answer (score 0):

You should use unix functions brk and sbrk if you want to build your own toy memory manager :)

It would definitely be alot easier to answer if you gave us the specific context of where you called free(app->slice) in your code, inorder for it to break.  This is because you should be able free memory by doing a free(app->slice).

Comment: While it's possible to use `brk()` and `sbrk()`, I'm not sure it is recommended.  Until the basic problems are sorted out, it is sensible and far easier to use `malloc()` et al in lieu of `brk()` or `sbrk()`.

Comment: Thank you I didn't know these functions!